# Using H2 database for integration testing in Grails

Tags: grails

My understanding is by default Grails using the H2 embedded database for testing.
My Datasource.groovy configures a local Postgres database as  a root datasoure

```
dataSource {

    driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

    url = ...
    pooled = true
    ...
```

But I don't want this used in integration testing. I would prefer to use the H2 embedded option.  So how do I override this for integration test environment and make it use embedded H2 database?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Place the baseline configuration in the dataSource block and override it with an environment block as explained in section [4.2 Environments](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#environments) of the Grails documentation.

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb:MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb:MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
            dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
            dbCreate = ...
            url = ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me - when I run my integration tests, it says it is setting the deployment to test, but it completely ignores my test datasource, which is mysql, and uses an unknown memory one instead, even though I have no mention of the h2 db in the entire datasourc.groovy.  Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question, but until now i didn't find an answer. Perhaps setting the field dialect inside Datasource.groovy like this:

```
test {
    dataSource {
           dbCreate = "update"
           dialect='org.hibernate.dialect.H2DialectPatch'
           url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"

    }
}
```